# Geodesics in Heisenberg's group

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

I'm doing Riemannian Geometry work and I can't justify whether or not there are geodesics in the Heisemberg Lie Group.
Can anybody help me!

Comment: There is not much context. So I just suggest [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1797).

Comment: Thank you, I have to show you are the geodesics of this group. @DietrichBurde

Comment: You can justify the existence of geodesics by constructing a left invariant Riemannian metric on the Lie group and then using the construction of geodesics in any Riemannian manifold,

Comment: Who are the invariant fields to the left of this Lie group?

Comment: I don't get the question. For any pseudo-Riemannian manifold (including Lie groups, with metrics invariant or not), we have that for any point and any tangent vector there, there is a geodesic starting at said point with the given inicial velocity. This is a general fact about differential equations.